# SQL Server domain name and user name formatting

Tags: sql-server

I am executing a SQL script in SQL Server Management Studio 2018. In my script I need to specify a user (including the domain - unsure if I need the server name).

So I have created a user `sam`, set the user type to `SQL user without login` and set the users role to `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter`.

I then execute my script but it gives me the error: `User or role 'MHT.sam' does not exist in this database.`

But I am almost certain I have added this user to the database (see my images below to double check). **Is my user and domain name format correct?** What do you think I am doing wrong?

[image]

Here's my domain and server:
[image]

Comment: You've created a user `sam`, which would be (probably) for a SQL login. If you want to create a user for a for a Windows Authentication you'd need to quantify the Domain the user's name: I.e. `CREATE USER [MHT\sam];`

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty obvious.

In your screen shot in the object explorer you have a user called `SAM`, but for sp_AddRoleMember you are using `MHT.SAM` user.

Your sp_addrolemember should also have only `Sam` something like...

```
Exec sp_addrolemember N'RunStoredProc' , N'Sam'
GO
```

Also to double check what your user type is what login it is mapped to and what really is going on, use the following query.

```
SELECT        
        d.name                  AS User_Name
      , d.type_desc             AS User_Type
      , d.default_schema_name   AS User_default_schema_name
      , d.create_date           AS User_Created_Date

      , s.name                  AS Login_name
      , s.type_desc             AS Login_LoginType 
      , s.is_disabled           AS Login_is_disabled
      , s.create_date           AS Login_create_date
      , s.default_database_name AS Login_default_database_name
      , s.default_language_name AS Login_default_language_name

FROM sys.server_principals s
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals d on s.sid = d.sid
WHERE d.name = 'Sam'
```